# How to remove certain rows if there are two values for same login id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
loginid       Status
========================
jo            deleted
jo            active
jo            discard
kir           active
user1         active
user1         deleted
```

The results shoud give me only

```
kir      active
```

rest login id should not be there.

Can you plesase help with the query

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Can't be both

Comment: Would you mind in show us what have yout tried ?

Comment: even after the edit from someone with common sense I still do not understand the question :(

Comment: @JackyCheng- one login id can have 1 or more status. I want result of login id where there is single status like Kir here in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
select *
from yourtable
where loginid in
(select loginid
 from yourtable
 group by loginid
 having count([Status]) = 1)
```

The `HAVING` clause ensures that only those `loginid` values that have a single `Status` mapped to them are selected. Note that this query will only **select** the required rows. If you want to delete the offending rows, you can do it like so:

```
delete 
from yourtable
where loginid in
(select loginid
 from yourtable
 group by loginid
 having count([Status]) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE
FROM login_table
WHERE login_id IN
  (SELECT login_id FROM login_table GROUP BY login_id HAVING COUNT(login_id)>1
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are missing rule, but try this :

It return all loginid that have no other status than active.

```
SELECT
    t.loginid
    ,t.Status
FROM
    table t
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT
            loginid       
        FROM
            table
        WHERE
            Status <> 'active') loginDuplicatedAndNotActive
    ON t.loginid = loginDuplicatedAndNotActive.loginid
WHERE
    loginDuplicatedAndNotActive.loginid IS NULL
    AND t.Status = 'active'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE  si
FROM    Tbl si
JOIN    (
        SELECT  login_id,Count(status)
        FROM    tbl
        GROUP BY
                login_id 
        HAVING  COUNT(status) > 1
        ) q
ON      q.login_id = si.login_id
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51372/1)**